# Redirect user after login to a secure document Joomla

Tags: authentication, redirect, joomla

I got a space on my website which is secured. You need to be connected to access it. If I click on a link in an email to access a page secured, I got redirect to my login page. I type my user/pass and after my login, I am redirect to my page.

However, when I do the same thing, but with a pdf document (and not a page), which is secured, Joomla ask me to log in. I enter my information, but I am not redirect to my document (the link clicked previously), I am redirect to my profile page....

Did someone already solve this problem?

I am using Joomla 3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try catching the event from plugin here is document page: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User and the event you need is onUserLogin

Comment: After review my code, I saw that my login form have an hidden field named : Return. When it's a page, the field is fill with the url of the page in base64. But when it's a document, the field is fill with "profile" in base64, and not with the url of the document... Any clue?

Comment: Return url in the hidden field : index.php?option=com_users&view=profile

Comment: Try to put document pdf in reserved menu voice and then call that url.